# APK build fails when compiling with 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'

Tags: java, android

Getting the following error when trying to build the APK.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   net/lingala/zip4j/core/HeaderReader.class

My gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
      buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
    compile 'eu.chainfire:libsuperuser:1.0.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: at first use `buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"`

Comment: add `compile group: 'net.lingala.zip4j', name: 'zip4j', version: '1.3.2'`

Comment: I made both changes, but still the same fault :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project in Android Studio and simply copied all of the old files, except for the gradel. It now it works fine to build the APK file. Unfortunately this doesn't really explain why the problem emerged in first place. I have included a copy of the new gradle file below but the only main differences is the support for “mulitdex” which didn't really make any difference if I removed from the first version of the gradle file.

But now it finally works so I am happy with that.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile group: 'net.lingala.zip4j', name: 'zip4j', version: '1.3.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```